# Overridding Up Navigation

Tags: java, android

I have an issue where both of my Activities have a contact button on each, when clicked it launches a new intent for the Contact Activity. Seeing as how I can only set the parent class as one of those two activites via manifest, the navigation when brought to the Contact activity will always return the user to the defined parent activity. I want it to basically return to the activity that opened it, which I guess would essentially make them both a parent ?

My guess would be to delete the parent from Manifest, and somehow programmatically override / add Up navigation that just calls finish() on Contact Activity when clicked?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: post your code what your have tried? Say you have Activity A , B & ContactActivity. You want to open ContactActivity from A and B , then .. i a not clear what your requirment

Comment: And I want the up navigation in Contact to return to either A or B, depending which fires the intent initially.

Comment: Not much code behind it, just setting the parent activity via Manifest to Activity A, so the up navigation is always returning to Activity A from the ContactActivity. Obviously setting a parent was not a good way of doing it since I want the up navigation to return to Activity A or Activity B, depending which initially opens Contact Activity.

Comment: see my answer.hope this is what you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the onOptionsItemSelected and handle the up navigation like below. Best practice is to override from a BaseActivity and extend the BaseActivity from your custom Activities.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: {
            finish();
            return true; // make sure to return true here.
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Does not work, still crashes but when I make finish() on a button, it works... odd? Up navigation still must be performing something else other than finish();, or lifecycle must be different ?

Comment: Sorry got it working now, forgot the return true; Why would I use return true; instead of break;

Comment: You need to post the code. This seems to be different issue . Are you launching any activity after finish?

Comment: Good. If your not returning true super.onOptionsItemSelected will be called and try to go back to the parent activity mapped to home.